# Why lucene doesn't require composite index, but relation database does?

Tags: database, relational-database, indexing, lucene

Lucene stores index for each field separetly. So when we perform query "fld1:a AND fld2:b" we iterate over Termdocs for first term and second term. This can't be faster. In case of database two separete indexes for fld1 and fld2 will work slow and only one will be used. In that case DB requres composite key for fld1 and fld2.

My question is. Why Can't DB utilize Lucene index algorithm for executing Boolean queries if it as fast as DB index and dosn't requires different combinations of columns?

Some details of Lucene Boolean Query search:
It utilize interface [TermDoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/org/apache/lucene/index/TermDocs.html). The main idea in using two methods `boolean skipTo(int)` and `boolean next()`. So it is doesn't depend on term order(popular or not popular term) because count of those method calls will be always as most infrequent term(due to skipTo method). So there are no need in hierarchical composite index, it will not bring any additional performance.

```
TermDocs t1 = searcher.docs(fld1:a);
TermDocs t2 = searcher.docs(fld2:b); 
int doc = -1;
t1.next(); t2.next();
while(t1.doc()!=-1 && t2.doc()!=-1) {
if(t1.doc()<t2.doc()) {
  if(!t1.skipTo(t2.doc)) return;
}
if(t2.doc()<t1.doc()) {
 if(!t2.skipTo(t1.doc)) return;
}
if(t1.doc()==t2.doc()) {
println("found doc:"+t1.doc());
t1.next()
}
}
```

Comment: `In case of database two separete indexes for fld1 and fld2 will work slow and only one will be used.`  This is only really true of MySQL.  Postgres doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Are you sure? It is also true for Db2.

Comment: Well, I definitely know it's not a problem for postgres =D  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html

Comment: I don't know for sure, but wouldn't Lucene spawn 2 threads to search fld1 and fld2 concurrently? Very broadly speaking, search engine indexes only use RAM resources, while relational DBs assume that the index will be swapped in and out from disk to RAM as needed. Avail RAM is a much more of a hard limit on the size of a search engine instance (running in prod, for instance), i.e. the number of terms, documents, etc that can be retrieved in milliseconds. While a DB has an extra layer that temporarily brings in fld1Index and fld2Index for the current query (plus system optimizations). Good Luck!

Comment: @shellter No lucene dosn't search in parallel. It utilize interface TermDoc(http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/org/apache/lucene/index/TermDocs.html).
The main idea in using two methods skipTo and next. So it is doesn't depend on term order(popular or not popular term) because count of those method calls will be always as most infrequent term(due to skipTo method). So there are no need in hierarchical composite index, it will not bring any additional performance.

Comment: @yara : Thanks for the clarification. Good luck on solving your problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think @Frank Farmer's comment gives you most of your answer: it's perfectly possible for an RDB to use multiple indexes even if they aren't "composite".

A more specific question has a harder answer: why don't RDBs use *Lucene's* multi-index-search paradigm?

Recall that Lucene uses an inverted index with a skip list; recall also that these are only efficient if the index is extremely sparse and the number of terms is very high.

In the type of column where you're likely to do a query like `where a = b`, the number of possible `b`s is probably pretty small, and hence the index will be relatively dense. So it makes more sense to use bitmaps (like PostgreSQL does) and gain the speedup of bit-level parallelism than to store it as a skip list and deal with pointer-chasing.

I should note that even Lucene uses bitmaps when combining filters with queries, so we might equivalently ask why Lucene doesn't use Lucene's search. My guess is that bitmaps are smaller and therefore more likely to fit in memory.

To the best of my knowledge, this is not a huge performance gain, so you probably can't make a very strong argument for either bitmaps or skip lists in the general case. But if I had to guess why the PostgreSQL devs went the bitmap route, I think it would be this.

Comment: Thanks, I now realize why Lucene skipTo works so fast - just because it is skip list. Now the problems seems clear to me.